# Why does this simple PHP/MySql script take so long to execute?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a Database table with about 50,000 records. I'm running a script which I wrote in PHP that will connect to my DB and update every record. However this takes an unimaginably long period of time to complete (I ran the script through the browser and it timed out. When I tried running it against a local DB it ran for over 40 minutes and still didn't complete).

**What I've got:**

A table where each entry has an *ID*, *Username* and a *JSON blob*.

Json blob:

```
{
    "user": {
        "Country": {
            "US": {
                "item": {
                    "property1": "value1",
                    "propertyBool": true,
                    "property2": "value2"
                }
            }
        },
        "Subscription": {
            "subscribed": false
        }
    }
}
```

**What I need to do:**

I need to parse the JSON blob and add more **countries**  under the `Country` property (the new Country will have the same structure as the current one (US) but different values. Because the properties under `item` will be different for each user, I need to parse JSON for every user individually.

At the end I want my JSON blob structure to look something like this:

```
{
    "user": {
        "Country": {
            "US": {
                "item": {
                    "property1": "value1",
                    "propertyBool": true,
                    "property2": "value2"
                }
            },

            "CA": {
                "item": {
                    "property1": "otherValue",
                    "propertyBool": true,
                    "property2": "yetAnotherValue"
                }
            }
        },
        "Subscription": {
            "subscribed": false
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code I'm running inside my PHP script to update it:

```
<?php

    db_connect();

    /*Get each user from the DB*/
    $qry_users = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE 1 = 1");

    /*Loop through each entry in DB*/
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_users)){
        /*Parsing the blob*/
        $user = json_decode($row['user']);

        $jsonAddition = /*parsing JSON here for the new bit of JSON that will be added in*/

        /*Adding the new Country to our current JSON blob*/
        $user->Country->CA = $jsonAddition;

        /*encoding JSON for adding it to DB*/
        $user = json_encode($user);

        /*Updating the current entry in the loop with the new JSON blob*/
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET user = '$user' where userId = '".$row['userId']."' ");
    }
?>
```

Does anyone know why this would take such a long time to execute? Is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: Row by row updating is agonizingly slow. Row by row inserting as well.

Comment: Is there a different way to achieve what I'm doing?

Comment: I don't see how you could change it to a table operation, I'm sorry.

Comment: I don't see any reference to transaction... I mean a COMMIT. I suppose that indicates that every UPDATE is within its own implicit autocommited transaction. That is not efficient if you have to update many rows. You could try to group the UPDATEs in explicit transactions... maybe 100 or 1000 per transaction. That usually boosts things a lot with other client-side architectures. I'd expect it to be the right thing to do in php too.

Comment: Thanks for that @Frazz
If I understand correctly this would 'batch' up 100 or 1000 UPDATEs into one 'request'? As opposed to sending the query 1000 times individually? How would I add this my current query?

Comment: I'm no php expert, so you'll have to look through the documentation to see how to implement explicit transactions in php. But it's not really like you think. The server still receives say 1000 separate requests, but it keeps them on hold till the commit request. COMMIT is costly as it is there that the server has to guarantee that updates are consistent and visible to other transactions. Forcing a COMMIT for every insert/update is ok only if you are updating a single row at a time with user input. Batch inserts and updates should be "batched" together to lessen the cost of COMMIT.

Comment: What access method does your table use? If it's MyISAM this business of batching a bunch of updates into a single transaction won't help.  Also, by giving up after 40 minutes, you're concluding that about 50 milliseconds per update (twenty per second) is too slow for you. You may want to be more patient.